# Using Motoman MH6 with ROS On-the-fly path planning

Tags: ros, motoman, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am interested to work with ROS and a Motoman MH6 DX100 robot about On-the-fly path planning. This robot model isn't available yet, but I want to include it. However, I dont know what we need in order to do it (I read something about MotoPlus SDK, MotoROS, a ROS package) but I amn't really sure with this.  Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191480/using-motoman-mh6-with-ros-on-the-fly-path-planning/) by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-28**:
You might want to send the [ROS-Industrial](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev) mailing list a message. People from Yaskawa actually subscribe to that list.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-28**:
Also: was your [previous](http://answers.ros.org/question/191233/how-can-i-use-motoman-stack-with-ros-indigo/) question answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swri-ros-pkg-dev/LSLZL_-LjIE)

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0